# How can i Reuse one screen for Multiple Activities?

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, reusability

I  have one XML with 20 fields in my case based on type we want show the form but every type need not all fields how can i hide the fields and show the corresponding fields for a particular type .I want reuse the same screen for All types but we want hide the fields without effecting the padding ?

Thanks in Advance.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hide fields that you don't want to show in the activity initially..

Comment: Yes But my requirement is show the corresponding fields for each type of Items the 20 fields is repeated in in 8 types of screens

Comment: but we need to show some fields from that 20 for each type not all?

Comment: @venkat -- can you give more explanation for whatever you explained so far I understood only one thing that you have 20 fields & few activities & you want to show some of the fields in each activity with same layout So i said just hide fields those you don't want to sh0w in your activity after setContentView